# Searching formula with vertical bar (absolute value) in Google

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

I'm wondering if it's possible to search a formula with vertical bars inside in Google. If I try to search:

[integral "|x^n|"](https://www.google.com/search?q=integral%20%22%7Cx%5En%7C%22&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Google is not able to understand that the vertical bars represent the absolute value. Maybe there is another way to specify this?

Comment: Try using "abs(x)".  Also see [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/)

Comment: Hello @talbi thank you for your comment. I know these search engines, their problem is that they consider only a small set of websites, instead Google is more powerful. E. g. https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28%20%5Cint%7B%5Cleft%7C%20x%5En%20%5Cright%7C%20%5C,dx%7D%20%20%5C%29%20%20#t=1644104676017